# Testing VueX store

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test different parts of VueX store. I keep mutations, getters and else in single file (index.js) but somehow it does not work when import that file into test file.
Here is my VueX:
Vue.use(Vuex);

`Index.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);


export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pickedDates:[]
  },
  mutations: {
    mutatePickedDates: (state, payload) => {
      state.pickedDates = payload;
    },
})
```

Now in `Store.spec.js` I want to test it:

```
import storeConfig from '@/store/index.js'

const store = storeConfig


test('check if state is working', () =>{
    const state = {
        pickedDates: []
    }
    const dates = ['1995-01-01', '1995-01-01']
    store.mutations.mutatePickedDates(state, {dates})
    expect(state.pickedDates).toBe(dates)

})
```

But I get error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mutatePickedDates' of undefined` when running test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches to testing vuex. First one is to unit test actions, mutations and getters. Second is to test working store directly.

### Unit Testing Mutations

If you want to test stores mutations isolated from components, I would recommend exporting them.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const mutations = {
  mutatePickedDates: (state, payload) => {
    state.pickedDates = payload;
  }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pickedDates:[]
  },
  mutations: mutations
})
```

Then you can import and test mutations directly.

```
import { mutations } from '@/store/index.js'

test('check if state is working', () =>{
    const state = {
        pickedDates: []
    }
    const dates = ['1995-01-01', '1995-01-01']
    mutations.mutatePickedDates(state, dates)
    expect(state.pickedDates.length).toBe(2)
})
```

### Use working Vuex Store

```
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import store from '@/store/index.js'

test('check if state is working', () =>{
    // initial state
    const state = {
        pickedDates: []
    }

    const dates = ['1995-01-01', '1995-01-01']

    // create local instance and vuex store
    const localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(Vuex)

    // commit mutation
    store.commit('mutatePickedDates', dates)

    expect(store.pickedDates.length).toBe(2)
})
```

Comment: But is there a way to test them in the setup i presented above?

Comment: you have 2 options. I added the second option to my answer. 
reference: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html#testing-a-vuex-store

Comment: Actually there I get error when trying to use second option. `[vuex] unknown mutation type: mutatePickedDates`

Comment: ofc you have to take the exported vuex instance you defined and not create one without mutations. I adjusted my answer. But since I do not have your code I cannot test it. If you cannot get this running after this explaination, you should carefully read through the documentation I have send. gl

Comment: If the code above does not work, you should export the initial object you pass to Vuex.Store() and create the store directly in the test instead of exporting the store. Just like the examples in the documentation.

Comment: I ended up using first method which certainly works. Thanks